# Can't connect IExtension object to BrowserHelperObject

Tags: javascript, c#, internet-explorer, bho

I'm trying to call a `BHO` plugin function from javascript, that `BHO` injected to page.

But:

1. `console.log(window.myExtension)` is "none" or "undefined"
2. `OnDocumentComplete` fires not on each browser start. (it's because of IE?)
3. `OnDocumentComplete` not fires on F5, just if set cursor in address field and press Enter (and see 2nd)

Complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Expando;
using SHDocVw; 
using mshtml;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using INISpace;

namespace IEPlugin
{

[ComVisible(true),
Guid("4C1D2E51-018B-4A7C-8A07-618452573E42"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IExtension
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void alert(string message);
}

// IObjectWithSite GUID
[ComVisible(true), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("FC4801A3-2BA9-11CF-A229-00AA003D7352")]
public interface IObjectWithSite
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetSite([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]object site);
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetSite(ref Guid guid, out IntPtr ppvSite);
}



[ComVisible(true),
 Guid("DA8EA345-02AE-434E-82E9-448E3DB7629E"),
 ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), ProgId("MyExtension"),
 ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IExtension))]
public class BrowserHelperObject : IObjectWithSite, IExtension
{
    private WebBrowser webBrowser;
    public void alert(string message) { System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("BHO: " + message); }

    public void OnDocumentComplete(dynamic frame, ref dynamic url)
    {
        if (!ReferenceEquals(frame, webBrowser))
        {
            return;
        }

        dynamic window = webBrowser.Document.parentWindow;
        IExpando windowEx = (IExpando)window;
        windowEx.AddProperty("myExtension");

        //window.myExtension = this;  crash that piece of shit

        this.alert("frame IS browser" + windowEx);

        HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;
        IHTMLScriptElement scriptObject = (IHTMLScriptElement)document.createElement("script");
        scriptObject.type = @"text/javascript";
        scriptObject.text = "console.log(window.myExtension);";
        document.appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)scriptObject);

    }

    public int SetSite(object site)
    {
        if (site != null)
        {
            webBrowser = (WebBrowser)site;
            webBrowser.DocumentComplete += new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
        }
        else
        {
            webBrowser.DocumentComplete -= new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
            webBrowser = null;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public int GetSite(ref Guid guid, out IntPtr ppvSite)
    {
        IntPtr punk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(webBrowser);
        int hr = Marshal.QueryInterface(punk, ref guid, out ppvSite);
        Marshal.Release(punk);
        return hr;
    }

        public const string BHO_REGISTRY_KEY_NAME = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Browser Helper Objects";

        [ComRegisterFunction]
        public static void RegisterBHO(Type type)
        {
            RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHO_REGISTRY_KEY_NAME, true);

            if (registryKey == null)
                registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(BHO_REGISTRY_KEY_NAME);

            string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");
            RegistryKey ourKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid);

            if (ourKey == null)
            {
                ourKey = registryKey.CreateSubKey(guid);
            }

            ourKey.SetValue("NoExplorer", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

            registryKey.Close();
            ourKey.Close();
        }

        [ComUnregisterFunction]
        public static void UnregisterBHO(Type type)
        {
            RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHO_REGISTRY_KEY_NAME, true);
            string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");

            if (registryKey != null)
                registryKey.DeleteSubKey(guid, false);
        }
    }

}
```